# Graphing the solid defined by: $D=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : xy \geq 1 \}$

Tags: graphing-functions

I am try to graph the solid defined by following but I have no idea as to where to begin:
$$D=\big \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : xy \geq 1 \big \}$$

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Thanks, I made the change.